# How to putExtra data using newest ActivityScenarioRule/ActivityScenario?[Espresso/Jetpack]

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing, android-espresso

There were added new classes to test Activities, such as [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule) and [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario)
And there is no documentation how to use them when you want put some extra data.

For now I've found two working ways, in short:

1) Use ActivityScenarioRule and put your extra in the method with @Before annotation using [#onActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#onactivity). **But**, there would be unnecessary data for some test cases.

2) Second, use ActivityScenario with [#launch(Class activityClass)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#launch) when you dont need extra and [#launch(Intent startActivityIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#launch_2) when you want put extra. **But**, this time I loose an ability to use [#onActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#onactivity) where can be placed common for all test cases

P.S. this is my first time of android testing :)

Answer (score 12):

I was able to solve this problem by using a static Intent in my test class. That way, my intent is instantiated before I pass it to my ActivityScenarioRule.

My espresso test class:

```
package your.package.tests.example;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider;
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class TestExample {

    static Intent intent;
    static {
        intent = new Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("YOUR_BUNDLE_TAG", "YOUR_VALUE");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
    }

    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<YourActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(intent);

    @Test
    public void yourTest() {
        onView(withId(R.id.simple_text)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

My espresso gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.1-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.1-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0-alpha02'
    ...
}
```

References:
Medium tutorial how to use espresso tests: https://medium.com/@heitorcolangelo/testes-no-android-com-espresso-parte-1-8d739672a235

Comment: it returns putextra null for me. anyone knows what to do?

Answer (score 6):

Personally i do it like that

```
lateinit var activityScenario: ActivityScenario<MyActivity>

@After
fun tearDown() {
    activityScenario.close()
}

@Test
fun myTest() {
    val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MyActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("key", "value") //obviously use a const for key
    activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch<MyActivity>(intent)

    activityScenario.onActivity {
        //whatever you like
    }
}
```

Comment: that throws this exception:
org.junit.internal.runners.rules.ValidationError: The @Rule 'activityScenario' must implement MethodRule or TestRule

Comment: In that case you should annotate it with @get:Rule

Answer (score 2):

What I've decided to do - marginally simpler than the other answers.

```
lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<MyActivity>

@After
fun cleanup() {
    scenario.close()
}

@Test
fun myTest() {
    val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MyActivity::class.java)
        .putExtra("key", "value")
    scenario = launchActivity(intent)
    // Your test code goes here.
}
```

You'll also need to add the below dependency to your gradle file

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.0'
```

Reference: https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/better-tests-with-androidxs-activityscenario-in-kotlin-part-1-6a6376b713ea

Answer (score 1):

From the Java doc on the deprecated `ActivityTestRule` it mentions:

> For simple cases where you want to launch the Activity before each test and tear it down after each test (eg you are using `ActivityTestRule(Class)`), convert
> directly to `ActivityScenarioRule`.
>
> If you need control over when to launch the Activity (eg you are using `ActivityTestRule(Class, false, false)`, use `ActivityScenario.launch`. Its recommended to wrap the launch in a try-block, so the Activity is closed automatically.

To convert cases that need to pass custom data in the Intent, I've gone with the following:

```java
final Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
final Intent intent = new Intent(targetContext, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("foo", new Foo());

try (final ActivityScenario<MyActivity> scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(intent)) {
    /* Here you have access to scenario.onActivity() */
}
```

> But, this time I loose an ability to use #onActivity where can be placed common for all test cases

I've decided to pull out common set-up into helper methods that I can call within the test as needed. Not as neat as a `@Before` block, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class IndividualPersonActivityTest {

    private val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), IndividualPersonActivity::class.java).apply {
        this.putExtra(IndividualPersonActivity.KEY_ID, "I1")
    }

    @get:Rule
    val activityScenarioRule = activityScenarioRule<IndividualPersonActivity>(intent)


    @Test
    fun treeSimplyStart() {
        // do what you want
    }

}
```